# AngularJS Filter on nested properties

Tags: angularjs, filter

I would like to create a filter on nested objects like this:

```
Object 1 :
 property1
 property2
 property3
 children : Child 1 :
             propertyChild1
             propertyChild2
            Child 2 :
```

And so on. An object can have multiple child. There is no depth limit specified.The problem is that I want to search only on certain properties of the object so I used:

```
 ng-repeat="groupLevel1 in groupLevel2.children | filter: {lineDescription: searchKeyword}"
```

This is searching on all levels but if a parent does not contain the searchKeyword, all the children (which may contain the search) aren't displayed. I want that all parent levels are displayed in order to display the children that contains the search keyword even if the parents do not match the search.

I tried some complicated script but it does not work:

```
appReportingHoliday.filter('globalFilter', function(){
return function(array, predicate){
    return array.filter(function(val){
        var formattedObj = parseFloatInternational(predicate);
        var re = new RegExp(formattedObj, 'i');
        var initialArray = [];
        initialArray.push(val);
        var childIsNeeded = false;
        var toReturnTemp;
        var parents = [];
        var toReturn = [];
        while(initialArray!=null){
            angular.forEach(initialArray, function (currentVal) {
                toReturnTemp = false;
                //We check if the val is concerned by the search
                toReturnTemp = re.test(currentVal.lineDescription) || re.test(currentVal.acquiredHolidays) || re.test(currentVal.tokenHolidays) || re.test(currentVal.availableHolidays)
                        || re.test(currentVal.dailyCost) || re.test(currentVal.valuation);

                if (toReturnTemp) {
                    //if it is, we need to add the result to the toReturn array and also the parents that we could have saved in the according array
                    toReturn.push(currentVal);
                    toReturn.push(parents);
                    parents = [];
                }
                else {
                    //else we save it in the parents array if a child is needed
                    if(currentVal.children!=null) {
                        parents.push(currentVal);
                    }
                }
                var index = initialArray.indexOf(currentVal);
                initialArray.splice(index, 1);
                if(currentVal.children!=null) {
                    angular.forEach(currentVal.children, function (currentChild) {
                        initialArray.push(currentChild);
                    });

                }
            });
            if(initialArray.length==0) initialArray = null;
        }
        return toReturn;
    });
}
});
```

The display is made like this:

```
 <tr class="groupReportingTreeDatatable" ng-repeat-start="groupLevel3 in myData | filter: {lineDescription: searchKeyword}" ng-init="$index &lt; 2 ? groupLevel3.hideRows = false : groupLevel3.hideRows = true;" ng-class-even="'dataTable_row1'" ng-class-odd="'dataTable_row2'" spinner-handler-directive="">
                        ...
<tr class="groupReportingTreeDatatable" ng-hide="groupLevel3.hideRows" ng-init="groupLevel2.hideRows = true"  ng-repeat-start="groupLevel2 in groupLevel3.children | filter: {lineDescription: searchKeyword}" ng-class-even="'dataTable_row1'" ng-class-odd="'dataTable_row2'">

                        ...


 <tr ng-hide="groupLevel2.hideRows || groupLevel3.hideRows" ng-repeat="groupLevel1 in groupLevel2.children | filter: {lineDescription: searchKeyword}" ng-class-even="'dataTable_row1'" ng-class-odd="'dataTable_row2'" ng-repeat-end="">
```

EDIT :
I tried something else which works for some searches but not all of them :(

```
appReportingHoliday.filter('globalFilter', function() {
return function (array, predicate) {
    return array.filter(function (val) {
        var formattedObj = parseFloatInternational(predicate);
        var re = new RegExp(formattedObj, 'i');
        var found = re.test(val.lineDescription) || re.test(val.acquiredHolidays) || re.test(val.tokenHolidays) || re.test(val.availableHolidays)
                        || re.test(val.dailyCost) || re.test(val.valuation);
        var child = val.children;

        while(child!=null && found == false){
            angular.forEach(child, function (currentChild) {
                if(found == false) {
                    console.log(currentChild.lineDescription)
                    found = re.test(currentChild.lineDescription) || re.test(currentChild.acquiredHolidays) || re.test(currentChild.tokenHolidays) || re.test(currentChild.availableHolidays)
                            || re.test(currentChild.dailyCost) || re.test(currentChild.valuation);
                }
            });
            child = child.children;
        }

        return found;
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to have a second variable where you flatten all of the children of the first one? You could define a recursive function doing that, something like...

```
var mainObject = ... ;//that's your object
var flattened = new Array();

function flatten(main,flat) {
    var children = main.children;
    for (var i=0;i<children.length;i++) {
         flatten(children[i],flat); // recursive call, depth-first
         delete children[i].children; // those are already treated
         flat.push(children[i]); // add children
    }
    delete main.children;
    flat.push(main);
}
```

Now you can filter on the properties directly.

Comment: I am really bad with recursive methods, I tried one but it didn"t wrk. Does the filter not to be applied on the var that is actually displayed on the page ? Because I do not see how I can use the second var if it is not actually used in the screen.
I added a new code below since I couldn't wrote the whole code in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to integrate this in my code. I cannot change the base variable because I need it in this structure to display it on the screen. I can create another flattened array but the filter has to be applied on the var I display, no ? So I cannot use the flattened var. I have to admit I am a bit lost ^^

I fixed the depth to 3 to make it easier so now I have a this:

```
appReportingHoliday.filter('globalFilter', function() {
return function (array, predicate) {
    return array.filter(function (val) {
        var formattedObj = parseFloatInternational(predicate);
        var re = new RegExp(formattedObj, 'i');
        var found = re.test(val.lineDescription) || re.test(val.acquiredHolidays) || re.test(val.tokenHolidays) || re.test(val.availableHolidays)
                        || re.test(val.dailyCost) || re.test(val.valuation);
        var child = val.children;

        if(child!=null && found == false){
            angular.forEach(child, function (currentChild) {
                if(found == false) {
                    found = re.test(currentChild.lineDescription) || re.test(currentChild.acquiredHolidays) || re.test(currentChild.tokenHolidays) || re.test(currentChild.availableHolidays)
                            || re.test(currentChild.dailyCost) || re.test(currentChild.valuation);
                }
                if(currentChild.children!=null && found == false){
                    angular.forEach(currentChild.children, function (currentGrandChild) {
                        if(found == false) {
                            found = re.test(currentGrandChild.lineDescription) || re.test(currentGrandChild.acquiredHolidays) || re.test(currentGrandChild.tokenHolidays) || re.test(currentGrandChild.availableHolidays)
                                    || re.test(currentGrandChild.dailyCost) || re.test(currentGrandChild.valuation);
                        }
                    });
                }

            });
            child = child.children;
        }
        return found;
    });
  }
});
```

The only problem that remains is that if the search is on a parent, I want all the child t be displayed but right now only the matched children are displayed :s I cannot find the parent from a child, I have only the link from parent to child not the other way around :s